# Count and print the number of tags in a google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a gDocs document with a number of tags like:

```
[open]
[draft]
[completed]
```

I’m looking for a way to build a summary at the beginning of the docs:
Number of Open items: X
Number of Completed items: Y

I think I should use regular expressions and google apps scripts but I’m really not familiar with the latest.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This counts the open tags.  I'm guessing you can get the rest on your own.

```
function countOpenTags() 
{
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var text=body.getText();
  var opens=text.match(/\[open\]/g);
  return opens.length;
}

function displayTagCount()
{
  var s=Utilities.formatString('There are %s [open] tags in this document', countOpenTags());
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Opens')
}
```

All in a single dialog.

```
function countMyTags(mode) 
{
  var mode=(typeof(mode)!='undefined')?mode:'open';
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body=doc.getBody();
  var text=body.getText();
  var tags=[];
  try{
    switch(mode)
    {
      case 'open':
        tags=text.match(/\[open\]/g);
        break;
      case 'draft':
        tags=text.match(/\[draft\]/g);
        break;
      case 'complete':
        tags=text.match(/\[complete\]/g);
        break;
    }
    return tags.length;
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

function displayTagCount()
{
  var s=Utilities.formatString('<br />[open]:%s<br />[draft]:%s<br />[complete]:%s<br /><script>function printDialog(){window.print();}</script><br /><input type="button" value="Print" onClick="printDialog();" /><br /><br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />', countMyTags(),countMyTags('draft'),countMyTags('complete'));
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Tag Summary');
}
```

Comment: It works. I created functions for the other tags but I cannot print all the counting in a single window.

Comment: The second version of your script (thank you!) returns this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null. (line 21, file "Code")
Dismiss

Comment: Ok, problem it that it doesn’t handle when it cannot find any specific tag

Comment: You can probably do it more elegantly but that eliminates the error.